# How do you calculate the input to the first linear layer of a CNN?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

So, I got this code of a CNN build with PyTorch: Pic of the CNN code [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orztf.png)

Until now I've been able to calculate the input size of the linear layer (self.fc) after the last conv1d block (b5 in this case) by printing the product of the last two dimensions of f5.shape in the forward function, but I need to automate the experimentation and I can't just print the value for each test and change the code.

My input tensor is also variable in size (I have signals as my data and I'm using a window to get X points per sample, so for example a 1020 window size will result in a 1020x1x3 tensor I guess, is a 1D CNN and I have 3 input channels).

So, how can I get the self.n_features parameter (the input of the linear layer) automatically using this code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a lazy version of [`nn.Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html), namely [`nn.LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html). In your case:

```
self.fc = nn.LazyLinear(n_class)
```

It will initialize its weights on the first layer inference.

Comment: That would be a wonderful and simple solution, but because of compatibility issues I'm stuck using PyTorch 1.2.0 and that class it's not implemented yet (maybe I should've mentioned that in my post, my bad).